# How i can downgrade my SQL file from 5.6 to 5.5

Tags: mysql, sql

i need some help regarding how to downgrade my sql database file from 5.6 to 5.5, because i did changed my hosting.my old hosting server was 5.6 and new server version was 5.5, i am getting error while i am importing the data base file..
support says:"you are running MySQL Server version: 5.5.51-38.2. Which is why you are having issues importing the database. You would need MySQL 5.6 for that database." ..any one can please help me in it ??

i have uploaded my sql file here please check: http://www88.zippyshare.com/v/bbzjmvCJ/file.html

and please fix it if you can. i am very thankful to you...
error i am getting while uploading is here :

```
CREATE TABLE `wpqc_o3n8w99opanda_leads_fields` (
  `wpqc_o3n8w99opanda_leads_fields`.`lead_id` int(10) unsigned,
  `wpqc_o3n8w99opanda_leads_fields`.`field_name` varchar(255),
  `wpqc_o3n8w99opanda_leads_fields`.`field_value` text,
  `wpqc_o3n8w99opanda_leads_fields`.`field_custom` bit(1) DEFAULT 'b\'0\'',
  UNIQUE `UK_wp_opanda_leads_fields` (`lead_id`,`field_name`),
  KEY `IDX_wp_opanda_leads_fields_field_name` (`field_name`)
)/*! engine=MyISAM */;
```

MySQL said:

> #1067 - Invalid default value for 'field_custom'

Comment: I'm sure your new host will upgrade if you ask them

Comment: Or just find a hosting service that has at least v5.6. Seriously, you did not check before changing a provider?

Answer (score 0):

The default value for a bit field should be `DEFAULT b'0'`  this is not a difference between v5.5 and 5.6, it is probably an issue with the export, which considered `b'0'` as a string and encapsulated it into extra single quotes and escaped the original  single quotes.

Comment: Hi Thanks for comment, can you please tell me how i can fix this issue ?

Comment: I thought I told you how to fix it by telling what the right default value looks like. I do not really understand what else I can do.